# Как в Intellij IDEA быстро создать GUI с помощью Swing?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, gui

Как в IDEA быстро создать GUI с помощью Swing?

Comment: [Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/designing-gui-major-steps.html) на официальном сайте есть пример как работать со swing

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko не компилируется

Comment: какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko main'a нет

Comment: значит либо правда мейна нет, либо в билде нет версии джавы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю насчет IDEA, но в старом добром и ныне полуживом [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/index.html) есть замечательный GUI визард, который генерит Swing'овские коды. Генерит почти правильно, если не увлекаться сильно редактированием контролов.

Ну а сгенеренный код всегда можно перекинуть в IDEA

Comment: Добро пожаловать снова к нам :)